# How can I use Pandasai which is 3rd party package in snowpark inside snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to access pandasai package which is not available in snowpark. So, I have put the file into stage.

[image]

Handler is:
[image]

And the code is simple pandasai operation:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

#import pandas as pd

from pandasai import SmartDataframe

 

def main(session: snowpark.Session):

 

  # Create the table if it doesn't exist

  session.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table3 (STATUS varchar(255))")

 

   # Insert a row into the table

  session.sql("""INSERT INTO my_table3 (STATUS) VALUES ('Fantastic')""").collect()

 

  # Query the table

  df = session.sql("SELECT STATUS FROM my_table3")

   

  # Create a SmartDataframe object from the Pandas dataframe

  smart_dataframe = SmartDataframe(df)

   

  # Query the Snowflake database using the SmartDataframe object

  filtered_dataframe = smart_dataframe.query("STATUS == 'Fantastic'")

 

  # Print the output of the code

  print(filtered_dataframe)

   

  # Print the contents of the DataFrame to the console

  df.show()

   

  # Return the DataFrame

  return df
```

Result Image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

To do or implement pandasai lib in snowpark inside snowflake

Comment: Are you sure you're importing it correctly? It should be something like `from pandasai.smart_dataframe import SmartDataframe`

Comment: Yes, I am importing it correctly because in local system it worked.